# Mobile App Azure, DataAnnotations

Tags: azure, data-annotations, azure-mobile-services

Hey I have a MobileService on Azure build with C#.

For this I have a data annotation to a database, something like

```
    [MaxLength(14)]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(4)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
```

How do I enable the same annotation on Mobile App int the service - DataObjects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seemed like the assembly was not added for the new using.

Therefore insert at the top

`using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

Go to the references in assemblies and find it and add. Your done :)

If this does not work there can be an issue with AspNet, try the following in the packagemanager:

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`

if it is allready installed you can update the package instead:

`Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost -reinstall`

Comment: And up you go... Strangely I didn't receive an error on referencing the namespace while I was missing the reference to the assembly in my project.